# Is it possible to make a EFI file to boot Yumi USB flash drive?

Tags: windows-8, boot, multi-boot, uefi, secure-boot

2 days ago I've bought an HP Envy laptop, which comes with Windows 8 pre-installed.
Before that I were using Yumi USB flash drive with a dozen of boot options to set-up the computers (e.g. re-partition the disk, setting up and repairing dual-boot Linux+Win7, etc.).
However with HP Envy I didn't figure out, how to boot from [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) USB flash drive. The main reason for this is probably that I've just met with UEFI and didn't figure out, how it works. Here is what I tried to boot from Yumi flash drive.

**HP Envy boot options**

With HP Envy I found, that if you press F11 on boot, you get a blue screen with
"Recovery. Your PC needs to be repaired. A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed. Error code: 0xc0000225" message and with 3 options below:

```
Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for Startup Settings
Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings
```

Options "Enter" and "F8" do nothing (show the same blue screen again), while "Esc" leads to the following startup menu

```
F1  System information
F2  System Diagnostics
F9  Boot Device Options
F10 BIOS Setup
F11 System Recovery
```

And F9 option allows me to "Boot From EFI File" (I can browse USB flash drive to locate it, but this won't help while I don't have it). Therefore I have the following question(s).

**The question**

Is it possible to create an EFI file for Yumi?
Or is it a wrong way to work with UEFI computers and I should do something different to do the usual disk-OS-boot tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used YUMI; however, based on skimming its main Web page, it looks like it sets up SYSLINUX to boot various image files from the USB flash drive. This type of configuration would have to be re-done using an EFI version of SYSLINUX or some other EFI boot loader (such as GRUB 2). You could experiment with this yourself, but I don't know of any tool that does this already or explicit instructions on how to do it. The closest I'm aware of is my [Managing EFI Boot Loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) page, which describes EFI boot managers generally. You might be able to piece something together after reading that (and particularly the pages on SYSLINUX and/or GRUB 2) and studying the way YUMI sets things up. This will *not* be a point-and-click solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

In the F10 menu there should be an option to change the boot order.  If you set USB to boot before the OS Loader, then any bootable USB media should boot - even if it is the old MBR style.

If YUMI is not GPT aware, don't use it to modify the disk in any way, since this could corrupt the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Easy2Boot](http://www.easy2boot.com/add-payload-files/adding-uefi-images/) and see if that will work. Just be sure to check out the tutorials on their site to get an understanding of the process of how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F10</kbd>, go to "boot", "enable legacy boot" then reboot. Hit the <kbd>F9</kbd> key and you will find the options of other boot devices. Aelect the yumi pen drive and you are good to go.